# Linux SSH Server (tunneling) without network tweaks such as port forwarding or firewall exceptions

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

**Background Info:**

My office is closing down due to COVID19 outbreak policies.
Unfortunately we do not have a VPN in place, and currently one of my coworkers has to going in every day to make commits for everyone who is working remotely--our repos are stored inside the office internal network.

**The Problem:**

I need to be able to get inside the internal network remotely using SSH, *without having to make any changes to network configuration* (I do not have access to the network devices). This means I would not be opening ports, or making firewall exceptions for example.

I was thinking of using a raspberry pi with a fresh linux image (any supported distro would be fine, I'm open to suggestions).

My goal is to plug the pi3 to my workstation ethernet port, and leave it there for the time being. I would not be able to do any physical reboots , etc.

I need a suggestion for a free tunneling solution that would be easy to set up and use for 1-10 people to be able to connect using a secure connection (SSH) and gain access to internal resources remotely.

**Question:**

I need suggestions for which distro would be nice and light enough for the pi3 to handle, and SSH server software to use.

I looked into OpenSSh which has been suggested in other similar threads, but it would require configuring firewall and opening port 22, which I cannot do.

**Other**

I've used Google Chrome's remote desktop in the past and it has worked wonderfully. I would set up the "host" machine with it, and then any other machine with Chrome (with the same account) could remote in without any sort of network configuration.
I guess I just need something similar to this, but instead of remote desktop I need an SSH solution. I would create a few root-enabled accounts to allow other devs to connect to it at the same time if possible.

Comment: The first thing to check is with a lawyer.  Unless your IT dept. gave permission this is likely cause for termination.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I asked my manager and normally it is against the company policy to use any devices that aren't provided by them. However due to the unusual situation where they had no time to prepare or put anything in place, he said that I could try anything that would work for the time being. 

In other words, I have the OK to do it. This is meant to be a temporary solution anyway, until the IT staff puts something in place. But again they weren't ready for it and there's nothing in the works for this currently.

Basically I need a way to work remotely as if I was at my desk...

Comment: Anyway, your question is off-topic since this is not about a program you are writing.  You will get more help on https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll make sure to post there as well.
I thought StackOverflow would be fine since there are tags for IT related content as well as programming related content.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem and will pass it along to my IT team for proper approval prior to putting in place. However I wanted to share the answer here in case anyone else ever has a similar situation.

As stated, be sure to check your company's policy and consult the proper channels before doing this sort of thing, as it can cause security risks and could get you fired... so be advised, do this at your own risk!

With that said, a "**Reverse SSH**" could be the solution to the problem. It allows you to connect to a machine inside of a network without having to open ports or firewall exceptions.

This isn't a good long term solution for most cases, but might be the workaround you need to do the trick in a pinch.